# Is there a way to access my music on Vista while I work on Ubuntu?

Tags: ntfs, music

I have installed Ubuntu using Wubi alongside Vista on my laptop.

Is there a way for me to gain access to iTunes that is on Vista?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply mount your windows drive in Nautilus (click the drives in the left pannel), and then with Banshee or other player import those songs.
If you want to automatically mount the drives in ubuntu, [here](http://ubuntutechnical.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/ubuntu-auto-mount-drives-on-login/)
is a link on how to do it.

P.S. For ITune, you woul require wine (as far as I know). The mounting is a solution if your music is on the windows drive.

Comment: Thanks bioshark .... does mounting take up memory and disk space?

Comment: No, it's just a link to your other drive.

Answer (score 0):

Sense your using a wubi install the drive C:\ of your windows is in the root filesystem whith the name of /host were you can find all of your windows folders including your music documents picture etc.... no need to mount anything.